# Gensim LDA model topic diff resulting in nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, gensim, lda

I am pretty new at topic modeling and Gensim. So, I am still trying to understand many of concepts. I am trying to run gensim's LDA model on my corpus that contains around 25,446,114 tweets. I created a streaming corpus and id2word dictionary using gensim. I am using num_topics = 100, chunk size = 85000 (loading 85000 tweets at a time)

I am using 
Gensim : 3.5.0
Numpy: 1.15.3

Here is the link to corpus and id2word dictionary: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FrJ8gJbiDqp3VC5syOjRVcQPcESdYOYa?usp=sharing

I don't know what I am doing wrong or how to solve this. The topic diff first hits inf and then nan , and I start getting same topic. 
Please help !!

Here is the code:

```
import pprint
import logging
import gensim
logging.basicConfig(filename='gensim.log',
                    format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s",
                    level=logging.INFO)
corpus = gensim.corpora.MmCorpus('disasterTweets.mm')
id2word = gensim.corpora.Dictionary.load('disasterTweets.dict')
id2word.filter_tokens(bad_ids=[id2word.token2id['eofeofeof']])
print('eofeofeof' in id2word.token2id)

lda_model = gensim.models.LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus,
                                       id2word=id2word,
                                       chunksize=85000,
                                       num_topics=100)
pprint.pprint(lda_model.print_topics())
```

Here are the errors I am receiving:

```
/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py:1023: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
 diff = np.log(self.expElogbeta)
/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py:690: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in add
  sstats[:, ids] += np.outer(expElogthetad.T, cts / phinorm)
/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py:700: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  sstats *= self.expElogbeta
/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py:690: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in add
  sstats[:, ids] += np.outer(expElogthetad.T, cts / phinorm)
/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py:700: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  sstats *= self.expElogbeta
Process ForkPoolWorker-30:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 105, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamulticore.py", line 333, in worker_e_step
    worker_lda.do_estep(chunk)  # TODO: auto-tune alpha?
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 725, in do_estep
    gamma, sstats = self.inference(chunk, collect_sstats=True)
  File "/home/ec2-user/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 662, in inference
    expElogbetad = self.expElogbeta[:, ids]
IndexError: index 287500 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 287500
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood reading the thread in Gensim Github Issues page [issue 217](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/217) it seems that is a bug and some people there have reported that the problem was resolved by changing some of the parameters. Please first check it out to see if the suggestions there solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I did had a look at the post before and after having closer look I was able to run model with workers = 1 and compromising on the number of topics. Although, coherence score is still nan and for more than 85 topics or so I encountered the same errors.